# regex lookahead AND look behind

Tags: python, regex

I have the following 2 variations of scraped data:

```
   txt =  '''Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt.''' # variation 1
```

and

```
    txt = '''Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist''' # variation 2
```

I'd like to make **one** regular expression that gets the percentage as a float, so in the first instance **3.0** and in the second **3.57**

I've tried this so far:

```
m = re.search(r'.{3}.%.{5}',txt)
txt = m.group().split("%")[1:]
txt = ("".join(txt)).replace(",",".")
print(txt)
```

Which works for the variation 2 but not variaton 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this code to grab your percent values and convert them into `float`:

```sh
>>> import re
>>> arr = ['Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt.', 'Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist']
>>> rx = re.compile(r'\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*(?=\s*%)|(?<=%)\s*\d+(?:[.,]\d+)*')
>>> for s in arr:
...     for m in rx.finditer(s): print (float(m.group().replace(',', '.')))
...
3.0
3.57
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/w3kILq/1)

[Online Code Demo](https://ideone.com/gEBCpE)

Comment: Using the float can handle the leading and traling spaces right? That is clever, something to remember :-)

Answer (score 3):

You might use an alternation with 2 capture groups, and check which group exists.

```
\b(\d+(?:\,\d+)?)\s*%|%\s*(\d+(?:\,\d+)?)\b
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XO84BP/1).

The pattern matches:

- `\b` A word boundary
- `(\d+(?:\,\d+)?)\s*%` Capture **group 1** - match a digit with optional decimal, optional whitespace chars and `%`
- `|` Or
- `%\s*(\d+(?:\,\d+)?)` Capture **group 2** - `\b` A word boundary - the other way around as in group 1
- `\b` A word boundary

For example

```
import re

regex = r"\b(\d+(?:\,\d+)?)\s*%|%\s*(\d+(?:\,\d+)?)\b"
test_str = ("Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt.\n"
            "Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist")

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):
    if match.group(1):
        print(match.group(1).replace(',', '.'))
    else:
        print(match.group(2).replace(',', '.'))
```

Output

```
3
3.57
```

If the spaces between the percentage signs are fixed, you could also use lookarounds to get a match only without groups.

```
(?<=% )\b\d+(?:,\d+)\b|\b\d+(?:,\d+)?(?= %)
```

See another [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OpIDAf/1).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"(?<=% )\b\d+(?:,\d+)\b|\b\d+(?:,\d+)?(?= %)"
test_str = ("Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt.\n"
            "Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist")

for s in re.findall(pattern, test_str):
    print(s.replace(",", "."))
```

Output

```
3
3.57
```

Comment: @Jan With re that would not work, you need the PyPi package for that. But good idea :-)

Answer (score 3):

Yet another one - using a branch reset with PyPi `regex`:

```
import regex as re

data = """
Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt.
Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist
"""
rx = re.compile(r'(?|(?P<value>\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*%|%\s*(?P<value>\d+(?:,\d+)?))')

for m in rx.finditer(data):
    print(float(m.group('value').replace(',', '.')))
```

Which yields

```
3.0
3.57
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/4LUqhw/1).

---

If you want to go completely crazy, use a subroutine *and* a branch reset (this is way over the top, admittedly):

```
(?(DEFINE)
    (?<value>\d+(?:,\d+)?)
    (?<before>%\s+)
    (?<after>\s+%)
)

(?|(?P<mwst>(?&value))(?&after)|(?&before)(?P<mwst>(?&value)))
```

See the other [**demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/3IBW7r/1/).

Comment: That is art :-)

Comment: @Thefourthbird: Thanks, mate. Sometimes I feel like painting with regular expressions, really. But few people really see the beauty in them.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend using `\d` inside the regex which matches a digit character. `?` can also be of aid to you which matches one or zero instances. The below regex would match both of the strings for you:

```python
re.search(r'([\d,]+)? % ([\d,]+)?',txt)
```

`[\d,]` simply matches a digit character or the character `,`. `[\d,]+` matches one or more of these characters. `([\d,]+)?` will match the characters if they exist, otherwise it will not attempt to capture them.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents:

```
(%?\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*%?)
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/DHk5eM/1)

- `(%?\s*` - Open 1st capture group holding an optional percentage sign and 0+ whitespace characters;

  - `(\d+(?:,\d+)?)` - A 2nd capture group holding your numerical value.
- `\s*%?)` - Close 1st capture group right after 0+ whitespace characters followed by an optional percentage sign.

Now you could try:

```
import re

data = """
Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt. 5,44
Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist
"""

for i in re.findall(r'(%?\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*%?)', data):
    if '%' in i[0]:
      print(float(i[1].replace(',', '.')))
```

Prints:

```
3.0
3.57
```

---

I believe you could cram the above in some list-comprehension.

```
import re

data = """
Käuferprovision: 3 % zzgl. gesetzl. MwSt. 5,44
Käuferprovision: Die Courtage i.H.v. % 3,57 inkl. MwSt. ist
"""

print([float(i[1].replace(',', '.')) for i in re.findall(r'(%?\s*(\d+(?:,\d+)?)\s*%?)', data) if '%' in i[0]])
```

Prints:

```
[3.0, 3.57]
```